# Double hashing give a number larger than the size of table

Tags: algorithm, hash, double-hashing

I have a hash table of size 11, implemented as an array.  I am attempting to use the double hash technique; I have already done most of my numbers. My hashing function is as follows:

```
h1 = key mod 11
h2 = 3*key mod 4
```

This gives me `h(k,i) = k mod 11 + i(k * 3 mod 4)` where i = 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

I already have slots 0, 1, 4, 8, 9, and 10 filled in. I am trying to insert 19.  This is my result for hashing 19:

```
1st time: 8  <-- collision 
2nd time: 9  <-- collision 
3rd time: 10 <-- collision 
4th time: 11 <--- well there is no index 11 table ends with index 10
```

What should I do?

Also, when they say, "Let the table have 11 slots," does that mean that the hash table has available slots from 0 to 10?

Comment: Did you `mean h(k,i) = key mod 11 + i*(key*3 mod 4)`?

Comment: yes that the function we have to use if we fail first time.

Comment: Ok, and what if all 11 slots are already filled?

Comment: your hash function produces values not in [0..10] range, try to mod it

Comment: I was looking over the book to make sure again. it says
h(k,i) (h2(k) +i*h2(k)) mod m . So Searge i am sorry i think i am wrong about the equation,

Comment: What is the mod m in the end. How can i find that out. All the infomation provided in the question is h1 and h2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change will fix the wrong hash table index calculation:

```
h(k,i) = (key + i*(key*3 mod 4)) mod 11
```

Comment: Yes, but you still have an issue with sequential entries (using any number 11 or larger will create a sequential pattern) and you don't account for a mostly full hash table.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone. Specially sergo,